# grep for expression and then grep for missing line

Tags: bash, grep

I need to check log files for `"RW";`
then I need to check 3 lines before and after it for a `variable=true;`
I want it to print the 3 lines before and after if `variable=true;` is not there.
This is what i have tried  `grep -B 3 -A 3 '"RW";' ./*`

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Perl to the rescue, using a "sliding window" of size 7:

```
perl -ne 'push @win, $_;
          next if @win < 7;
          print @win if $win[3] =~ /"RW";/
                     && ! grep /variable=true;/, @win;
          shift @win;
         '
```

If `"RW";` can appear closer to the beginning or end of the file than 3 lines, it won't be caught.